# Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal open at the current project directory (mac)?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When I open [Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) on macOSX it defaults to my home `~/` directory rather than the current project root.

I've been through the settings and there isn't anything obvious I've done from the defaults, and reverting all `"terminal.integrated.*"` settings doesn't rectify the problem..

*What am I missing?*

Answer (score 1):

Searching the closed GitHub issues turned up [this comment from Tyriar](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34101#issuecomment-329535156):

> It looks like you're using bash, this definitely works just fine. I suspect you are doing a `cd` or `pushd` in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.